# sqoop export gives java.nio.BufferOverflowException with table(~120 columns)

Tags: mysql, export, sqoop

I am trying to export a table to maria db; however most of the table are working fine ,but there is a table with ~120 columns which is getting bufferoverflow error.

```
2017-05-11 13:33:36,674 INFO [main] org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InternalUtil: Initializing org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe with properties {name=default.temp_searched_sp, numFiles=4, columns.types=bigint,varchar(254),timestamp,timestamp,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,string,bigint,string,timestamp,timestamp,string,string,string,double,string,bigint,string,string,timestamp,timestamp,string,string,timestamp,timestamp,bigint,bigint,string,string,string,boolean,string,string,timestamp,timestamp,string, serialization.format=1, columns=sequence_id,id,est_received_at,received_at,advertisers_on_page,context_accept,context_accept_charset,context_accept_encoding,context_accept_language,context_akamai_origin_hop,context_akamai_reputation,context_alexatoolbar_alx_ns_ph,context_authorization,context_cache_control,context_cdma1989,context_client_ip,context_connection,context_content_length,context_content_type,context_cookie,context_d_token,context_dnt,context_el_auth_param,context_fooheader,context_gateway_ip,context_giga_transport,context_host,context_iorad_extension,context_iv_user,context_library_name,context_library_version,context_myrefer,context_oppo_request_type,context_orig_host,context_origin,context_pragma,context_prefer,context_q_token,context_ra_sid,context_ra_ver,context_referer,context_s_token,context_save_data,context_sm_user,context_surrogate_capability,context_transaction_id,context_true_client_ip,context_ua_cpu,context_up_recursive_request,context_user_agent,context_usertoken,context_via,context_wk_utd_ip,context_ws_grp,context_x_akamai_config_log_detail,context_x_angi_applicationversion,context_x_angi_featureflags,context_x_angi_proxyversion,context_x_angi_requestid,context_x_angi_sourceapplication,context_x_att_deviceid,context_x_bluecoat_via,context_x_browser_session,context_x_clickoncesupport,context_x_client_id,context_x_csix_custid,context_x_csix_custkey,context_x_cw_pageurl,context_x_elastica_gw,context_x_forwarded_for,context_x_forwarded_port,context_x_forwarded_proto,context_x_icm,context_x_imforwards,context_x_int,context_x_iws_via,context_x_mwg_via,context_x_newrelic_id,context_x_paas_uid,context_x_personasinteractive_addon,context_x_psa_client_features,context_x_psa_client_options,context_x_real_ip,context_x_request_id,context_x_requested_with,context_x_rl_forwarded_for,context_x_sfs_embed,context_x_sharepath_rum_enabled,context_x_target_proxy,context_x_wap_profile,context_xroxy_connection,event,event_text,location_info_advertising_zone,location_info_search_zip_code,est_original_timestamp,original_timestamp,results,search_for,search_params_filters_categories,search_params_filters_distance_from_provider,search_params_filters_first_name,search_params_page,search_params_query,search_params_type,est_sent_at,sent_at,sort_sort_by,sort_sort_field,est_e_timestamp,e_timestamp,total_pages,total_results,user_id,query,search_type,test_user,category_id,edh_raw_file_name,est_load_timestamp,utc_load_timestamp,edh_bus_month, rawDataSize=112904662, columns.comments=nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull, numRows=155793, serialization.lib=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE={"BASIC_STATS":"true"}, totalSize=113060455, serialization.null.format=\N, transient_lastDdlTime=1494509566}
2017-05-11 13:33:37,971 ERROR [Thread-13] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[Thread-13,5,main] threw an Exception.
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.send.SendExecutePrepareStatementPacket.send(SendExecutePrepareStatementPacket.java:105)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executePreparedQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:578)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:279)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.execute(MariaDbServerPreparedStatement.java:369)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:233)
```

I am running sqoop on aws emr.

Sqoop command i am running is :

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/Web --username stage --password stage --table  searched_sp_UAT --staging-table searched_sp_UAT_stg --clear-staging-table --hcatalog-table temp_searched_sp
```

Do let me know if anybody could give me some pointers on it; or has faced similar one.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Sqoop issue. Looks like the DB is not able to handle the huge staging data. Any ideas on what is the size of the data you are trying to move as tables.
Does any of your data contain BLOB/CLOB?

Check this: [link](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-270)

Comment: After facing this issue i have been trying with 1000 records.No the data doesn't have BLOB/CLOB.
Also if i reduce the column to 81 it works just fine, but with one more column addition again i hit the error.
I tried shuffling columns, just to see if there is any issue with 81st or 82nd column but it seems its just linked somehow to the number of columns i have been exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks very much like this bug: [CONJ-270](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-270)

1. you are using a MariaDB JDBC connector, instead of the regular MySQL one *(cf. your stack trace)*
2. Sqoop uses a `PreparedStatement` with a lot of parameters *(cf. your stack trace)*
3. Before V4.1 the MariaDB connector had a bug on `PreparedStatement` with lots of parameters

So I strongly suggest that you switch to a **regular** MySQL JDBC  driver that is **widely used and thoroughly tested**.
Don't use exotic software unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank Samson, i was able to solve the issue i was facing by using the latest version of maria db jdbc driver jar.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Samson, i was able to solve the issue by using the latest version of maria db jdbc driver jar.
I did saw the CONJ0270 earlier but overlooked/didn't doubt it as the drivers jars are already provided by aws emr. But yes i also confirm its the same issue(CONJ0270) .